# Making R script available via Shiny app (textbox that shows R code, similar to Code Sample)

Tags: r, shiny

I was hoping there would be an easy way to paste an R script (VERY much like how Stack Overflow allows for Code Sample to be posted) into a Shiny app.  I believe it can be done with textOutput or HTMLOutput but was hoping there would be an easy way to paste into a box for someone so they could just copy into their own R session.  This particular bit of code is long, and hopefully I can just paste it into a box.  I guess the other option is making the script available for download.  Thank you!

Comment: You could use the [`shinyace`](https://trestletech.github.io/shinyAce/) package

Comment: I often use a `shiny::textAreaInput` with editing disabled for easy access to multi-line raw text.